# Largest power of 10 that divides $(44^{11})\times(35^{13})$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find the largest power of $10$ that divides $44^{11}\times35^{13}$.

I'm sort of lost on how to work this out. I know how to do this if it is going into a factorial (i.e. "what is the largest power of $7$ that divides $50!$") but I'm not sure how to do it with two numbers being multiplied together.

Any help to get started is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$$44^{11}\times35^{13} = 2^{22}\times 11^{11}\times 5^{13}\times7^{13}$$

The largest power of $10$ dividing this is $10^{13}$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you chose to do this? And how you got the answer? Thanks

Comment: He factored the numbers and then exponentiated.

Comment: So am I just looking to get factors of 10? i.e. the 2^22 and 5^13?

Comment: yeah, and he looked for the smallest of the exponents.

Answer (score 0):

We have $x=44^{11}\times 35^{13}=(2^2\times 11)^{11}\times (7\times5)^{13}=10^{13}\times(2^9\times11^{11}\times7^{13})$.

Let $y=\frac{x}{10^{13}}=2^9\times11^{11}\times7^{13}$

$\therefore 10^{13}|x$

Now $10\not|y\implies 10^{14}\not|x$.

$\therefore 13 $ is the highest power of $10$ we need.